# Camunda Example clarification

Tags: camunda

Am new to Camunda when am developing the camunda process flow in usertask am assign the assignee through properties but it not assign to particular user.
and am worked on ubuntu 14.0.4 and camunda with BPMN 2.0 first example am trying. 
Can any one help me? And one more clarification if we are create the Html forms and its also not reflect when we start the process with credentials demo/demo and when include the service task binding with class in `.bpmn` file 

and am facing the following error in tomcat log file:

I am working on following environment:
OS:ubuntu14.0.4
Eclipse:Luna
jdk:1.8
tomcat:7
Camunda:Camunda BPM platform v7.3.0.

am trying to execute the following example

"https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/bpmn20/deploy/"

and this is my bpmn file:

SequenceFlow_1
            SequenceFlow_7
        
        
            SequenceFlow_1
        
        
        
            SequenceFlow_7
            SequenceFlow_8
        
        
        
            SequenceFlow_8

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.camunda.bpm.getstarted.loanapproval.LoanApprovalApplication
org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: Exception while performing 'Deployment of Process Application Loan Approval App => Deployment of process archive 'loan-approval': One of the attributes 'class', 'delegateExpression', 'type', or 'expression' is mandatory on serviceTask. | loan-approval.bpmn | line 17 | column 150

at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.spi.DeploymentOperation.execute(DeploymentOperation.java:134)
at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jmx.MBeanServiceContainer.executeDeploymentOperation(MBeanServiceContainer.java:148)
at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.spi.DeploymentOperation$DeploymentOperationBuilder.execute(DeploymentOperation.java:209)
at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.RuntimeContainerDelegateImpl.deployProcessApplication(RuntimeContainerDelegateImpl.java:87)
at org.camunda.bpm.application.AbstractProcessApplication.deploy(AbstractProcessApplication.java:51)
at org.camunda.bpm.application.impl.ServletProcessApplication.contextInitialized(ServletProcessApplication.java:131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1930)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: One of the attributes 'class', 'delegateExpression', 'type', or 'expression' is mandatory on serviceTask. | loan-approval.bpmn | line 17 | column 150

at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.xml.Parse.throwExceptionForErrors(Parse.java:188)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.BpmnParse.execute(BpmnParse.java:267)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer.deploy(BpmnDeployer.java:105)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.DeploymentCache$1.call(DeploymentCache.java:62)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.DeploymentCache$1.call(DeploymentCache.java:59)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:485)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.DeploymentCache.deploy(DeploymentCache.java:59)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.DeploymentManager.insertDeployment(DeploymentManager.java:47)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.deploy(DeployCmd.java:177)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd$1.call(DeployCmd.java:93)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd$1.call(DeployCmd.java:82)
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.runWithoutAuthorization(CommandContext.java:485)
```

Comment: Post the bpmn file too, please.

Answer (score 3):

The [new Camunda Modeler](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/modeler/camunda-modeler/) produces BPMN models that require Camunda version >= 7.4.0, 7.3.3, 7.2.6 to run (see https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/modeler/).

The reason is that the namespace for Camunda extension elements and attributes has changed from `http://activiti.org/bpmn` to `http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn`. The new modeler produces models that use the new namespace and that can therefore not be executed on Camunda platform versions that don't support it. Assuming that you use this modeler, you'll have to upgrade Camunda.

As an alternative, you can use the [deprecated Eclipse plugin](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/modeler/eclipse-plugin/). Again, make sure to choose the correct version that works with 7.3.0.

Comment: Am using eclipse Luna with camunda 3.0.0 and camunda version is  camunda-bpm-tomcat-7.3.0.tar.gz these are the files am using, am not found name space related to activiti in my bpmn document

Comment: And that is the problem. Read https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/modeler/eclipse-plugin/update-sites/. You'll have to use modeler version 2.7.1 with Camunda 7.3.0.

Comment: no am using the camunda modeler 3.0.0 only not 2.7.1

Comment: Modeler 3.0.0 DOES NOT WORK with Camunda BPM 7.3.0. You can either use Camunda BPM 7.4.0 or Modeler 2.7.1.

Comment: thanks thorben. this solved the problem. accepting your answer.

Comment: still am facing the problems with the html forms are not loaded can any help me